I have tried to update my AGP to latest version and after that I can not build my project :(
Could not create task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.


Could not create task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eu.obsys.staffkeeper"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 59
        versionName "Amentet"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
//        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'eu.obsys.staffkeeper'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:4.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0'
    modules {
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7") {
            replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8") {
            replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.1.2'
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.13.0"
//    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Please help me because this is a core app and need to make new functions in it.
Thank you
I have tried to use google and chatgpt but nothing seems to work. :(

Did you fix it?

Delete the Build Folder and try again. Also, make sure you use compatible AGP and Kotlin Gradle plugin versions. Also, check the gradle wrapper properties. Check the Android Logs from Help > Show Logs in Finder.
If nothing works, revert the whole thing and upgrade the project step by step, Firstly try upgrading the Android Studio. Then get help from AGP Upgrade Assistance.

Thank for the solution, the bad thing is that after reverting everything still can not compile.
I have tried to delete the build folder but no success,
Android studio is up to date - iguana 2023.02.01 Patch 1
